# How can I display a List(Of Object) which has single objects and child List(Of Object)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

Limited to using v2.0 of .Net framework (we use VB.net) due to environmental constraints on our servers.

I've got an ASP.net webpage which pulls data from a webservice that performs checks on user accounts in active directory. Operators can check multiple accounts at one time using the web interface. The webservice returns a list(of AccountCheck) objects which themselves contain single properties like username, email address, and List(of AccountError) objects which contain multiple properties.

So the account check objects look like this:

```
Username
FriendlyName
Email
AccountError1 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError2 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError3 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError4 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError5 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc

Username
FriendlyName
Email
AccountError1 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError2 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError3 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError4 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError5 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc

Username
FriendlyName
Email
AccountError1 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError2 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError3 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError4 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
AccountError5 > Message > Weight > ResolverTeam > etc
```

etc

What I want to do is using some kind of repeater, create multiple panels or divs which contain labels showing the username, email etc, and a gridview which has the accounterror list bound to it to show all the errors. The users could be checking 2, 5, 7 accounts at once, and is dynamic.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Repeater with nested repeater for error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to nest two list controls; for example, a repeater and a gridview, or a repeater and a repeater, depending on how much control you need over the layout. The relevant part is to data bind the DataSource of the inner control to the inner list:

```
<asp:Repeater ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Username") %>
        ...
        <asp:GridView DataSource='<%# Eval("AccountErrors") %>' ...>
           ...
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I get the error "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs" using this method. Looks nice and simple though.

Comment: @Tom Pickles: Are you sure you got the `#` after the `<%`?

Comment: This worked: DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccountErrors")%>'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this using a DataList:

```
<table width="595px"> 
    <asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataKeyField="<ID>" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" runat="server" Width="100%">      
        <ItemTemplate> 
           <tr> 
              <td> 
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="+" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'></asp:LinkButton>     
              </td> 
              <td><%#Eval("<COLUMN NAME>")%></td> 
              <td><%#Eval("<COLUMN NAME>")%></td> 
              <td><%#Eval("<COLUMN NAME>")%></td> 
           </tr> 
           <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server"> 
               <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" Width="100%"> 
                   <ItemTemplate> 
                       <tr> 
                          <td><%#Eval("<CHILD OLUMN NAME>")%></td> 
                          <td><%#Eval("<CHILD COLUMN NAME>")%></</td> 
                          <td><%#Eval("<CHILD COLUMN NAME>")%></</td>                            
                       </tr> 
                   </ItemTemplate> 
               </asp:DataList> 
           </asp:Panel> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:DataList> 
</table>
```

And when the user clicks the LinkButton/Button in DataList1, do something like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //pass index of item in command argument 
    int itemIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);       

    //find the pnlChildView control 
    Panel childViewPanel = (Panel)DataList1.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("pnlChildView"); 
    if (childViewPanel != null) 
    { 
        //toggle visibility of childViewPanel and bind child list if panel is visible 

        if (childViewPanel.Visible) 
        { 
            DataList childList = childViewPanel.FindControl("DataList2"); 
            if (childList != null) 
            { 
                int keyValue = (int)DataList1.DataKeys[itemIndex]; 

                //bind the list using DataList1 data key value 
                childList.DataSource = <DATA SOURCE>; //get data using keyValue 
                childList.DataBind(); 
            }   
        } 
    } 
}
```